# Cannot Create an Interpreter in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, ide, interpreter

I downloaded `Python 3.8.`

I downloaded `PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.4`. Saved it in new folder in the Desktop directory.

In PyCharm, when I click on `File > New Project`, I...

1.) Have the location set to `C:\Users\User\Desktop\newProject`

2.) Have New environment using set to `Virtualenv`

3.) Have Base interpreter set to `C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe`

I have a Windows 10 Home computer

When I click on the `Create` button, I get the attached error.

What can I do?[image]

Comment: You need to setup and Interpreter

Comment: Why is `python.exe` present inside `WindowsApps`.  Please follow the simple installation guide for python. You might run into many other problems later.

Comment: @PrashantKumar That's where it went into by default when I downloaded it. You think I should try uninstalling it and putting into another directory? Any suggested directory? WindowsApps is a folder that is hidden and that I cannot get into.

Comment: Yes. Default should not be into that directory. I would suggest reinstalling `python`. It should go directly into `C:/` drive or `C:/ProgramFiles`.

Comment: Went ahead and uninstalled and reinstalled Python 3.8.

It works now in a new directory! Thanks, @PrashantKumar

Comment: Great to know that. Glad I could help. :D

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says it has access problem while accessing `python.exe`. Files inside WindowsApps are for systems use and cannot be accessed manually by users due to access permission.

Also you installation does not seem right as `python.exe` is present inside `WindowsApps`.

Please follow the simple installation guide for python. You might run into many other problems later.

I would suggest reinstalling python. It should go directly into `C:/` drive or `C:/ProgramFiles`.